# Objective C Google Maps API public key function

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

At the moment I'm having an issue with producing a public key for a given Google Maps Web Services API query.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth) stipulates that the signature must be produced with a modified base-64 HMAC-SHA1 hash, on the path and query part of the URL.

However using this function, and testing it with [this tool](https://m4b-url-signer.appspot.com) shows that it isn't working correctly.

```
+ (NSString *) hmac:(NSString *)data withKey:(NSString *)key{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"-"];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"];
    return hash;
}
```

I am calling this function where data has been precent encoded;

```
[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a sample Objective C code - is there any particular reason that you are not using them and some of the google functions in your code? In particular the equivalence of CKey is not plain 7 bit asCII (as coded in your sample) but Base64 (rfc4648Base64WebsafeStringEncoding). For the unfamiliar, Base64 is typically uses in mime Mail to allow attachments to go through plain text  email years ago (prior to HTML Mail) problem is if google thinks that your key is base 64 and it is not, the decoding will change your key - example base64 abcedfg = iy in ascii.  ... so google is not getting the correct decoding key from your URL.

There are other differences but I guess most of them are just format.

Comment: Where is the sample Objective C code? The only sample snippets I could find that relate to this are in C# and Java. All the Objective-C code is in relation to the actual SDK API, from which you cannot resolve paths from.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the sample Objective C code?

Comment: The link to the sample Obj-c : [urlsigner.m](https://github.com/googlemaps/url-signing/blob/gh-pages/urlsigner.m)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for your url signing : https://github.com/youssman/GMUrlSigner

I am interested in your feedback and comments ;-)

Comment: this link is broken. Can you provide another one?

Comment: @ParthDoshi please try again. Its OK now